# Create one long string from multiple lists of strings

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop

I am writing this back-end code to filter through a dataframe using df.query(). I have two lists from which I need to make this new string which will be passed as the query. Can anyone help me out?

```
list1 = ['Product == "Dress"', 'Product == "Shoes"', 'City == "Mumbai"']
list2 = ['|', '&']
```

```
#expected output
new_string = "Product == "Dress" | Product == "Shoes" & City == "Mumbai""
```

This is my code:

```
res = ' '.join([' '.join(x + i for i in list2) for x in list1])
print(res)
```

And this is the output I am getting which is wrong:
[image]

Comment: please cite the code as text, not with image links

Comment: len(list2) is always equal to len(list1)-1?

Comment: Yes!
len(list2) is always equal to len(list1)-1

Comment: Your expected output is unachievable due to "nested" double-quotes. What are the constraints on *list1* and *list2*. Do they always have 3 and 2 elements each respectively? What would be the desired output if *list1* had, for example, 4 elements?

Comment: If
elements in list1 = n
then
elements in list2 = n - 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```py
' '.join(value for pair in zip(list1, list2 + ['']) for value in pair)[:-1]
```

Comment: Thanks for such a quick reply. I tried it and this was what I got: ['Product == "Dress"', '|', 'Product == "Shoes"', '&']
It left the third element of my first list and the resultant is a list instead of one whole string. If you could help me with this it would be great. Thanks again for the response though.

Comment: Oh my god! You are a savior. It worked for me! I have given an upvote but I do not have enough reputation but when I do I swear I'll come back and upvote again! Thank you so much again

Answer (score 1):

How about creating a list of the relevant products, and using a query that check whether or not the value appear in the list, and also requiring the city to be Mumbai?

It's cleaner and the code is easier to maintain

Filtering script:

```
releavnt_product = ['Dress', 'Shoes']
df.query('(Product in @releavnt_product) and (City == "Mumbai")')
```

**Here an example:**

```
test_data = [
        {'Product': 'product1', 'City': 'city1'},
        {'Product': 'product2', 'City': 'city2'},
        {'Product': 'Dress', 'City': 'city3'},
        {'Product': 'Dress', 'City': 'Mumbai'},
        {'Product': 'product3', 'City': 'city2'},
        {'Product': 'Shoes', 'City': 'city2'},
        {'Product': 'Shoes', 'City': 'Mumbai'},
        ]

df = pd.DataFrame(test_data)
df
```

Output:

```
    Product City
0   product1    city1
1   product2    city2
2   Dress   city3
3   Dress   Mumbai
4   product3    city2
5   Shoes   city2
6   Shoes   Mumbai
```

Filtering script:

```
releavnt_product = ['Dress', 'Shoes']
df.query('(Product in @releavnt_product) and (City == "Mumbai")')
```

Output:

```
    Product City
3   Dress   Mumbai
6   Shoes   Mumbai
```

Comment: That is an innovative solution. Thanks!

Comment: Happy to help, if it helps, you're welcome to upvote and if you think it a better solution than the others then I would appreciate if you can mark this as a accepted solution :)

Answer (score 1):

With the requirement that `len(list1) == len(list2) + 1` then you can have a function to combine them and then join

```py
def combine(lst1, lst2):
    it = iter(lst1)
    yield next(it)
    for item in lst2:
        yield item
        yield next(it)

list1 = ['Product == "Dress"', 'Product == "Shoes"', 'City == "Mumbai"']
list2 = ['|', '&']
res = ' '.join(combine(list1, list2))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a variation on the answer from @rudolfovic that doesn't involve removing redundant characters.

The assumption here is that *list1* is of length N and that of *list2* is N-1 (as stated by OP) and N > 0

```
list1 = ['Product == "Dress"', 'Product == "Shoes"', 'City == "Mumbai"']
list2 = ['|', '&']

new_list = list1[0] + ''.join(f' {a} {b}' for a, b in zip(list2, list1[1:]))

print(new_list)
```

**Output:**

```
Product == "Dress" | Product == "Shoes" & City == "Mumbai"
```